# Google Sheets / Excel - "if A, then B, if D, then E" matching

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

In Google Sheets or Excel, is there an easy way to insert values into a cell based on one of several possible values of another cell?

In other words,

- If `A1` contains "red", then `B1` should be filled with "hazard"
- If `A1` contains "blue", then `B1` should be filled with "normal"
- If `A1` contains "green", then `B1` should be filled with "proceed"

What's the syntax to write this kind of matching?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "Contains" do you mean anywhere in the cell like `This cell is Red` or that is the value of the cell an only that word is in the cell.

Comment: You can nest a lot of IF statements this way, but a lookup table would likely greatly simplify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"blue","green","red"},{"normal","proceed","hazard"})
```

[image]

Note the lookup values must be in alphabetic order.

Comment: When offering this sort of solution, I find it is prudent to mention that `{"blue","green","red"}` must be in ascending alphabetic order.

Comment: because of the binary search, even just the first letters are enough `=LOOKUP(A1,{"b","g","r";"normal","proceed","hazard"})`

Answer (score 1):

Use below line in B1 to get an answer. Make sure to have the correct spelling in A1 that you are looking for or else you will see FALSE if A1 is empty or spelled wrong.

```
=IF(A1="red","Hazard",IF(A1="blue","normal",IF(A1="green","proceed")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach based on the cells' color

Option Explicit

```
Public Function ColorIndexes(Rango As Range) As Variant
 Application.Volatile
 If Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
  ColorIndexes = "Hazzard"
   ElseIf Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 24 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 23 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
    ColorIndexes = "Normal"
     ElseIf Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 50 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 35 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 48 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 12 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 56 Or Rango.Interior.ColorIndex = 14 Then
      ColorIndexes = "Proceed"
       Else
       ColorIndexes = "Not matched"
      End If

End Function
```